# nested 2 ng-app's on the same page

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application (let's call it A) and now I want to have this ng-app inside another ng-app (let's call it B) that's I'm having.

As AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)) So probably I'm looking for refactoring my code.

A solution that I thought about is to make a directive out of ng-app A and re-use it in ng-app B. Is that a good idea? or someone has found a better solution here?

example of the code:

```
<html ng-app="appB">
   <div>...markup of appB </div>
   <div ng-app="appA"> .. markup of appA </div>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the function of both apps? When you create an app with `angular.module('myApp', [])` the array at the end allows you to include dependencies, essentially other angular apps. Depending on the structure/purpose of `appB` `appA` could include it as a dependency that way.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you're trying to do. You could have A be a directive or controller in the module B.

Comment: are you sure? to put another ng-app inside this Dependancy Injection array? i'll give it a try. currently the controller of appA is linked to module appA. the problem is that now I want it to be linked to the module appB.
What those apps are actually doing is not relevant. you can think of appA to be a chat window where appB is the entire web-page.